# How do I banish the Evernote Helper once and for all in Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, boot, login, evernote

I want Evernote to open when I need it and then I want it closed when I close it.

I've repeatedly removed the helper from my login items, yet it keeps reappearing. Apparently, every time I open Evernote, it reintroduces itself to my login items.

How do I make it stop?

---

UPDATE: A new version fixes issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just opened Evernote and went to *Preferences > General* (tab).  At the bottom of the window *untick* "**Keep Evernote Helper running in the background when I quit Evernote**"

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not actually work. The Evernote Helper returns when the system reboots (and no, it is not listed as a startup item).

Answer (score 3):

You can easily stop the helper application, I've done the following and it's stopped loading:

- Open Evernote, and go to preferences
- On the General tab, turn off the 'Show Elephant in Menu Bar' option
- On the Shortcut tab, clear all of the shortcuts by clicking the little cross next to them 
  close the preferences window
- Quit Evernote through Evernote, then quit Evernote from the menu bar
- Open System Preferences and go to Accounts
- Select your Account and go to Login Items
- Highlight Evernote and press the <kbd>-</kbd> button to remove it.
- Close System Preferences and restart your machine.
- Restart your computer and the Evernote helper does not start.

Comment: easily? Not sure if that count as easy.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: You can't, it's a zombie.
Actual Answer: Unless you stop using Evernote and remove it from your system, you cannot remove Evernote Helper. Evernote Helper is the helper application associated with Evernote that provides functionality and communication between the Operating System and Evernote. Simply put, Evernote cannot function without the helper application. The helper application in this case is used to get the web snippits, pictures, and videos that you want to save to your notebook.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion; but I don't need any of the clipping functionality. I only need the actual collection of notes and the ability to edit them directly. So there's no need for the helper to run for me. Furthermore, I don't understand how it manages to create a login item entry without my permission, and think that that should be able to be blocked.

Comment: If you just want to edit the notebook, why not just use the website since you don't need the functionality of the application? Anyway, if you really really want to get rid of the helper application delete /Applications/Evernote.app/Resources/EvernoteHelper.app though bad things may happen if you do it(i.e. Evernote explodes).

Comment: Yeah I've switched to web only considering my infrequent use. Never tried getting rid of the helper app but maybe if I start using it more frequently I will. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> (Solution from [post on MacRumors](http://forums.macrumors.com/showpost.php?p=10051980&postcount=2) by [sethwalt](http://forums.macrumors.com/member.php?u=435109), who cited
>   another post on another site but did not provide a direct link):

The user "authorizes" Evernote Helper indirectly: Evernote sets some global keyboard shortcuts by default, and Evernote Helper listens for these key combinations. By implicitly "authorizing" the keyboard shortcuts, you "authorize" the app that makes them work. So goes Evernote's pretzel logic.

Deactivate all of the global keyboard shortcuts in Evernote's preferences:
[image: Go to Evernote Preferences, the Shortcuts section, and click the x's to remove all the global keyboard shortcuts.]

The Evernote Helper will stop loading itself when you reboot.

Comment: Does not work. I have all the shortcuts disabled, and the Helper still lodges itself in the list of items to run on boot.

Comment: Well shoot. It had stopped loading for me, but maybe there is a second setting involved in disabling the Helper.

Answer (score 0):

My preference menu shows "Save Data at Log Out", only. I have no real option. MacBook Pro, Evernote v10.4.3

Comment: Please disregard my post as my Mac is not running on OS X 10.6. but on 10.15.7. Sorry